# Sprint NetGear 341U USB Modem

Tags: usb-modem

I connect my Sprint NetGear 341U USB Modem to my computer but ubuntu 12.04 did not recognize it.

Comment: Connect to PC wait a few seconds and then type `dmesg` on a terminal window. There should be some messages about USB activity. Please edit your question to include those.

Answer (score 1):

The reason my NETGEAR 341U usb modem was not connecting is i skip a step in the Instructions (AC341U Linux Support Guide v1_2.pdf and Linux Support S2.12N2.21.zip):

Device Driver
Provided in the zip file, are two drivers Gobi-Serial and Gobi-Net. Gobi-Serial driver is used to communicate with AT serial port. Gobi-Net driver is used to make data
connections.

System Requirements
The instructions about device driver installation specified in this document are Linux
distribution independent. The device driver supports Linux kernel versions from 2.6.x to
3.5.0.23. This document uses screenshots from Ubuntu 12.04 to show the Network-
Manager behavior.

You can check your kernel version of Linux with these commands:

```
uname –r
lsb_release –a
```

Installation
Installation requires administrative privileges for your Linux system. Copy the
Gobi-Net and Gobi-Serial driver folders to your desktop and then to to `/usr/src`

Example:

```
sudo cp –avr /home/user1/Desktop/GobiNet /usr/src
sudo cp –avr /home/user1/Desktop/GobiSerial /usr/src
```

Once you have copied the driver folders to `/usr/src` issue the following commands
to recompile the drivers.

```
cd /usr/src/GobiNet
sudo make all
sudo make install
cd /usr/src/GobiSerial
sudo make all
sudo make install
```

I reread the instructions and did what they said.

My NETGEAR 341U usb modem works great!

Comment: When I try and make GobiNet I get c compile error about a f_dentry item not being in a struct.

Comment: /usr/src/GobiNet/QMIDevice.c:3366:28: error: ‘struct file’ has no member named ‘f_dentry’

Comment: oh i replaced them with f_path.dentry and it works.